# Firebird SQL запрос с группировкой, заголовки групп

Tags: firebird, sql

Есть запрос:

```
select  max(scl.id), emp.name,
        case scl."TYPE"
             when 1 then emp.height ||'/'|| emp.cloth_size
             when 2 then emp.boots_size
        end as "size",
        coalesce(dis.date_give, 'Не выдано') as "date_give"
  from employers emp
        join spr_rate_cloth src on src.id_prof = emp.profession_id and src.id_clothes in ('1' )
          left join distribution dis on dis.id_clothes = src.id_clothes
              and dis.id_emp = emp.id
              left join spr_clothes scl on scl.id = src.id_clothes
  where (dateadd(month, src.period, dis.date_give) < '13.06.2012')
  or (dateadd(month, src.period, dis.date_give) < cast('NOW' as date))
  or dis.date_give is null
group by emp.sex, 2, 3, 4
```

Можно организовать средствами SQL вывод результатов запроса так, чтобы для каждой группы выводился подзаголовок:

```
"Заголовок группы1"
  Запись1
  Запись2
  ...
"Заголовок группы2"
  Запись1
  Запись2
  Запись3
  ...
```

Comment: Запрос по моему не рабочий
в SELECT одно в GROUP BY другое
Так как вы хотите не выйдет сделать средствами SQL.
Разве что сделать еще одно поле и туда выводить заголовок группы рядом с вашими записями

Comment: Запрос рабочий. group by  может использовать не только имена столбцов, но и их порядковые номера, а также столбцы, которые не указаны в результатах выборки.

Comment: Про еще одно поле и заголовок группы - интересно... надо подумать...

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью функции в `firebird`

в запросе перед `SUSPEND;` нужно проверку ставить и выводит название группы.

получается в одном элементе цикла будет 2 `SUSPEND`

к примеру

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SEARCH_ACTOR(
     NAME VARCHAR(50))
 RETURNS (
     // тут ваши переменные если нужно
     TITLE VARCHAR(50),
     ACTOR VARCHAR(50),
     PRICE NUMERIC(18,2))
 AS
 DECLARE VARIABLE i INTEGER; // переменная локальная
 BEGIN
   FOR
     // тут ваш запрос типо этого
     SELECT FIRST (:i) TITLE,ACTOR,PRICE FROM PRODUCT
     WHERE ACTOR CONTAINING :NAME 
     INTO :TITLE,:ACTOR,:PRICE // это 
   DO
   BEGIN 
     IF (PRICE<30)THEN 
         // тут передача значений в :TITLE и другие 
         SUSPEND;
     SUSPEND; // этот suspend для вывода самой строки
   END
 END
```